# Videos scaling in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: video, vlc

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 in my Dell Inspiron 13 7000. All the videos are displayed as a small square box at the center of the media player. Black or blue color covers the remaining area of the media player. Minimizing the media player window (tried VLC and SM Player) leaves just the video right on top of the screen and the rest of the media player window gets minimized. This is quite annoying. Have gone through multiple posts that suggest changing Aspect Ratio, Crop value, "Always on top" fields etc. None of them seem to do anything at all. Starting to doubt if Ubuntu hasn't yet been capable of support the new hardware(as it is a relatively new laptop model). Please suggest a solution if anyone has been able to get this issue fixed.

Please find the output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Device 06fd
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with my relatively new TUXEDO N24_25JU

Graphics: Intel® Skylake ULT GT2

It seems to be related to the graphics controller. My system:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 2425
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I found a workaround this entry: [askubuntu - 729177](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710960/video-display-problems-ubuntu-on-asus-ux305-skype-and-vlc-and-other-programs)

There it says:

*... go to VLC Tools, Preferences, Video, and select at Output "OpenGL GLX video output (XCB)" then the problem disappears and everything is normal.*

That worked for me.