# Skype Video Call Screen keeps flashing and Camera Problem

Tags: skype, camera

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Application: Skype 4.3 for Linux.

Whenever I start a Video Call, I can see the person on the other side but the screen keeps flashing ceaselessly.

Furthermore, the person on the other side and I, can only see a closeup of my face. So I need to move away from the screen in order for the other person to see my face.

```
sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA 
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 07
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
```

Help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide details regarding your graphics and webcam setup. [edit] your question and include the output of  `sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA` and `lsusb`

Comment: probably your graphics problem, go to additional drivers tab in software and updates to check your graphic drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I also have chipset Intel 915 and I had the same problem with video calls in Skype.

Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 (from 16.04.1) helped me and completely solved this problem.

I believe that problem is solved in new version of Linux kernel. You can also try this [fix](https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix) if you don't want to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me, was using the `nomodeset` option in the grub bootloader. There are two methods to set `nomodeset`:

1. Temporary:

   - While booting press and hold shift in order to see the grub menu
   - Choose the entry you want to change (in a normal installation the first entry) and press **e** to edit it
   - Look for `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` before it
   - Finally press **F10** to boot.

If this worked for you, you can use the permanent way for all bootups.

2. Permanent:

   - edit `/etc/default/grub` (for example: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`)
   - change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`
   - Finally update the grub config: `sudo update-grub`

The next time rebooting, you don't have to specify the boot option.

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 4.4 kernel on Lenovo i310 laptop.

The output for `sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA` is the following:

> description: VGA compatible controller
>   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
>   vendor: Intel Corporation
>   physical id: 2
>   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>   version: 07
>   width: 64 bits
>   clock: 33MHz
>   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
>   configuration: latency=0

*This answer is partially copied from last answer at [When I start my camera in video call on Skype 4.1. incoming video is flashing blue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250932/when-i-start-my-camera-in-video-call-on-skype-4-1-incoming-video-is-flashing-bl#269216)*

Comment: A good answer, but can you explain what to do for the OP instead of just a link?  You can post your link in the comments instead as a duplicate, or you can expand your answer to be more thorough.  This makes it easier to follow for everyone :)

Comment: @ThatGuy How's an answer suggesting to use `nomodeset` **permanently** is a good answer?

Comment: @CelticWarrior - Good enough to provide an answer when there wasn't one.  If you want more info, ask the person who posted it.  It's still a better solution than *no* solution.  I only edited and cleaned it up.