# Intel® HD Graphics 530 compatibility with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, graphics, screen, intel, thinkpad

I've just bought a Thinkpad T460p with Intel® HD Graphics 530 and installed 16.04, but the images on the screen have been flickering ever since and today I failed a skype call because the video kept "flashing" blue light.
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was using the `nomodeset` option in the grub bootloader. There are two methods to set `nomodeset`:

1. Temporary:

   - While booting press and hold shift in order to see the grub menu
   - Choose the entry you want to change (in a normal installation the first entry) and press **e** to edit it
   - Look for `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` before it
   - Finally press **F10** to boot.

If this worked for you, you can use the permanent way for all bootups.

2. Permanent:

   - edit `/etc/default/grub` (for example: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`)
   - change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`
   - Finally update the grub config: `sudo update-grub`

The next time rebooting, you don't have to specify the boot option.

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 4.4 kernel on Lenovo i310 laptop.

The output for `sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA` is the following:

> description: VGA compatible controller
>   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
>   vendor: Intel Corporation
>   physical id: 2
>   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>   version: 07
>   width: 64 bits
>   clock: 33MHz
>   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
>   configuration: latency=0

*This answer is partially copied from last answer at [When I start my camera in video call on Skype 4.1. incoming video is flashing blue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250932/when-i-start-my-camera-in-video-call-on-skype-4-1-incoming-video-is-flashing-bl#269216)*